# Implementing dark mode in priceline design-system

Tags: reactjs, themes, darkmode

I am using [priceline design-system](https://github.com/priceline/design-system) and I confused about its dark mode support.
What is the best way for implementing dark mode when using this design system? Should I create separate theme for dark or there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ThemeProvider>` for this, like so:

```
    <ThemeProvider
  theme={{
    palette: {
      primary: {
        base: '#ff001d',
        dark: '#ffa52f'
      }
    }
  }}
>
  <Button>Custom</Button>
</ThemeProvider>
```

This outputs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxtd0.gif) with red being normal and orange being dark. It switches on mouse hover, but that's not shown with the GIF recording software I used.

With javascript you can do it using the following:

Syntax:

```
getPaletteColor(colorShade)(props)

getPaletteColor(color, shade)(props)

getPaletteColor(shade)(props)
```

Usage:

```
const Component = styled.div`
  color: ${getPaletteColor('primary.base')};
`
```

I'm not too sure about the javascript part myself, but it's correct according to multiple sources.

Comment: Dark in this object is the darken color of base and doesn't mean that this dark color used in dark mode. I think we should create whole theme for dark mode.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you meant for a dark mode for example when an iPhone's dark mode is on, I thought you meant like a dark edition of a component. Sorry about that. If you are creating for something like that, you probably do want to make a new theme in my opinion.

Comment: Yes. Do you know a way to automatic create dark theme palette from existing light palette?

Comment: No, the only way to do it is to either copy the existing one and edit from there or to start from scratch.